# ADB is causing kernel panics in OS X

Tags: adb, macos

***The following question is irrelevant. While MDM is problematic in many other ways, it is not responsible for the kernel panics.***

I also learned that Motorola mistakenly cites that its drivers must be installed to use ADB, this is not the case for OS X, which is the OS in question.

---

I have a Motorola X 2013 Developers edition. The ADB drivers for the phone are part of another software provided by Motorola called the Motorola Device Manager, and it caused 3 kernel panics on my laptop today, and more than I can count over the last week before I isolated the responsible package. I linked 2 kernel panic logs below, but this is the last line in the console before the crash every time.

12/22/16 8:13:16.000 PM kernel[0]: stalling for detach from Motorola ADB Interface

Then all hell breaks loose. It appears that the driver crashes when the computer enters sleep mode while the phone is plugged in. And no, it doesn't matter if the ADB is activated or not.

I've contacted Motorola about it and they said that they have never heard of this happening before, but they'd look into it. I have no expectations of them fixing it any time soon.

http://pastebin.com/yBHzWK2E

My question is, is there any alternative that would allow me to use the Android Debug Bridge with my phone?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try this : http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-x/development/recovery-unofficial-cwm-recovery-moto-x-t2406409

Comment: @esQmo I'm using a Mac and that driver is for Windows. Also, the download page is hosting viruses. My anti-virus goes nuts. I'd recommend removing the link from this page.

Comment: What like has viruses?! XDA Developers is a serious website !  And you didn't specify which OS your computer was running.

Comment: The link provided to the drivers on the page is what I'm talking about, not the site you linked. I know I didn't provide the OS, sorry about that. That's not your fault, but mine. However, interestingly enough, I uninstalled the software and the drivers appear to be unouched. Hopefully this stops the panics.

Comment: `adb` does not require any extra *drivers* to work on Mac besides the generic Apple USB driver.

Comment: just FYI: the `Motorola ADB Interface` string in the log does not come from any software on your computer - it is just a string from the phone's USB descriptor.

Comment: I learned that this morning. I completely uninstalled the Motorola Software and the kernel panics continue. This goes deeper than the Motorola Software.

Comment: would you like to edit out all that unbased and misdirected hate towards Motorola from your question then?

Comment: It's still problematic in many other ways, but sure.